# I can't figure out why my website glitches out on a smaller screen. What do I do?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code. It is frustrating me so bad.

```css
html {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #3D56E3;
  margin:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
#title {
  background-color: #A8B5ED;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  margin: 20px 900px 30px 0;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
#title:hover {
  color: #271573;
  transition: 0.5s;
 }
.intro {
  background-color: #A8B5ED;
  border: 2px solid black;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  margin: 90px 900px 30px 0;
  text-align: left;
  top: 8px;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
 }
 marquee {
   box-shadow:0 0 10px black;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   border-bottom: solid 2px black;
   background-color: black;
   right: 0;
   color: white;
   z-index: 2;
   width: 100%;
 }
.Projects {
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 20px 900px 30px 50px;
  left: 1120px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 0;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 50%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  background-color: #A8B5ED;
}
#Projects-Header:hover {
  color: #271573;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
a:link {
  color:#2333DE;
}
a:visited {
  color: #7855D9;
}
a:hover {
  color: #4B6BEB;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
  color: #092AAD;
}
#footer{
  color: white;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <!--Website by Keyblademaster33-->
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://keybladia.site11.com/style.css"/>
  <link type="icon/ico" rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico?v=2"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://keybladia.site11.com/home.js">
  </script>
 <title>
 Keybladia | Home Page
 </title>
</head>
<body>
     <marquee title="Site News" scrollamount="5">
     The Future is now, Thanks to Science!!! </marquee>
<h1 id="title">Welcome To Key's Website</h1>
<p class="intro"> Sorry for almost quiting on this website. I got frustrated
   and quit working on the website for about a month and a half. In the end,
   I couldn't give up and started working again. Hopefully, It should not happen again because
   I have more vigor than I ever did before. And to show how sorry I am, I redesigned the
   entire home page of the website.</p>
   <a href="https://plus.google.com/116883163929378015997" rel="publisher"></a>
   <div class="Video">
   </div>
  <div class="Projects">
  <h3 id="Projects-Header">Projects</h3>
   &nbsp; Site Navigation
  <ul>
    <li><a title="Now you don't have to hit the back button" href="http://keybladia.site11.com/"> Home </a></li>
    <li><a title="Them updates" href="http://keybladia.site11.com/pages/update_notes.html"> Site Updates </a></li>
    <li><a title="The future is now!" href="http://keybladia.site11.com/pages/future_plans.html"> Future Plans </a></li>
    <li><a title="Fight the Man!" href="http://keybladia.site11.com/school"> School </a></li>
  </ul>
  &nbsp; Cool Links
  <ul>
    <li><a title="Codecademy" href="http://www.codecademy.com/">Go here to learn code!</a></li>
    <li><a title="Reese Trcalek Inc." href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCY9Y9OyMwToDklOQ0-buegA">My YouTube Channel</a></li>
    <li><a title="Too Many Tags!" href="http://www.w3schools.com/">Coding References</a></li>
    <li><a title="You can't handle the code!" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Coding Help</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p> This website is created by Keyblademaster33 in 2014 - 2015 </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please I ask for help. Tell anything about other problems you see in the code. I have tried for about a month or so to figure it out. Here is the link to my website as well if that will help. http://www.keybladia.site11.com/

Comment: It's doing exactly what you told it to do.   Using absolute positioning for block elements that should be in document flow will usually give similar results.   I'd suggest you rebuild the html and css using floats and margins instead of positioning.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ay2Lav3c/15/
Just messed with it a little.
Customize it however you want.

```
    body {
background-color: #3D56E3;
}
#title {
display: inline-block;
background-color: #A8B5ED;
border: 2px solid black;
font-family: Times New Roman;
text-align: left;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
}
.intro {
background-color: #A8B5ED;
border: 2px solid black;
font-family: Times New Roman;
text-align: left;
top: 8px;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 90px;
right: 250px;
margin-right: 50px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;

}
marquee {
box-shadow:0 0 10px black;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
border-bottom: solid 2px black;
background-color: black;
right: 0;
color: white;
z-index: 2;
width: 100%;
}
.Projects {

border: 2px solid black;
position: absolute;
top:0px;
right: 10px;
width: 200px;
top: 0;
height: auto;
padding-left: 5px;
background-color: #A8B5ED;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.Projects - you could use a float: right; instead of fixed position with margins.

```
 .Projects {
  border: 2px solid black;
 float: right;
 width: 200px;
 top: 0;
 height: auto;
 max-height: 50%;
 padding-left: 5px;
 background-color: #A8B5ED;
```

}